# What are the Pathfinder classes relying the least on the player's dice rolls?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class

Let's assume a player has very bad luck (as in, most attack rolls result in failures, with a bad record of 1s' showing up at the worst moments).

**What are the classes that are the least reliant on the player's dice rolls for binary (succeed or fail) effects?**

Note: One example would be the fireball-hurling wizard: While the player would need to launch d6 damage, and the targets need to roll a saving throw, the fireball itself always succeeds, and the damage is always a lot of dices, minimizing the impact of a 1.

Comment: Do you mean any dice rolls, or this player's rolls only?

Comment: It seems we have a friend in common. Is he Brazilian?

Comment: As a player with impossibly bad luck, this is often my goal. (My alternative goal is to overwhelm the luck gods with my rolls, ensuring that at least one will be successful.) Narrowing this *could* work, to something like *How can a mundane warrior roll the least amount of dice and still defeat his foes?* or *What arcane caster needs to make the fewest number of player-facing rolls to contribute meaningfully?* but I doubt it. Instead, I think you might be better off overall first developing a build then asking how to optimize it so as to reduce die rolls on the player's part.

Comment: @enkryptor: Player attack rolls, mostly.

Comment: @ShadowKras: He's French. That's me actually. T_T

Comment: Following the [on hold] setting, the question was asked on Paizo's forum: https://paizo.com/threads/rzs42iit?What-are-the-Pathfinder-10-classes-relying

Comment: Yeah, after @HeyICanChan's reply, I was wondering how many people exist that *cannot roll anything higher than a natural 1 for 60% of their rolls*.